# Show $|xy-x_0y_0|<\epsilon$: necessary assumptions on $x,y$

Tags: limits, inequality

From Spivak's *Calculus*, problem 1.21:

Prove that if 
$$|x-x_0| < \min \left( \frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|+1)},1 \right)\qquad |y-y_0|< \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}$$
then $|xy-x_0y_0|<\epsilon$.

---

My question is that it seems it is sufficient to assume
$$|x-x_0|<\min \left( \frac{\epsilon}{2(|y_0|)},1 \right)\qquad |y-y_0|< \frac{\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}.$$

Why do you think Spivak put in the extra assumption there?

If it is not evident why the lesser assumption is sufficient, I'm happy to elaborate.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff My question is: if I'm doing the problem right, the problem assumes more than it needs to. Is there an evident reason why it would?

Comment: What if $y_0=0$? I guess Spivak does it to avoid meddling with that.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ah, of course!

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Notice $xy - x_0y_0 = xy + y_0x - y_0x - y_0x_0 $. Hence, using triangle inequality, we obtain:

$$ |xy - x_0y_0| = | xy + y_0x - y_0x - y_0x_0 | \leq |x||y-y_0| + |y_0||x-x_0| < \frac{ |x| \epsilon}{2( |x_0| +1)} + \frac{ |y_0| \epsilon }{2( |y_0| +1)} < \frac{ |x| \epsilon}{2( |x_0| +1)} + \frac{|y_0|\epsilon}{2|y_0|} = \frac{ |x| \epsilon}{2( |x_0| +1)} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Since $|y_0| + 1 > |y_0| \implies \frac{1}{|y_0|+1} < \frac{1}{|y_0|} $

Also, notice $|x -x_0| < 1 \implies x < 1 + x_0 \implies |x| < |1+x_0| \leq 1 + |x_0| $. Hence,

$$\frac{ |x| \epsilon}{2( |x_0| +1)} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \frac{(1+|x_0|)\epsilon}{2(|x_0|+1)}+ \frac{ \epsilon}{2} = \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$
The problem is now solved.

I hope this helps